# Error when running bash script for creating a new directory

Tags: windows, bash

I want to know how to find a file path in bash script using shell Script . I have some folders in my system .The folders are SCRIPT,SRC,OUTPUT . My current path is `c:/user/Desktop/project` . I have a `setup.txt` file inside `OUTPUT folder` . I have a `script` inside `c:/user/Desktop/project/SCRIPT` folder :

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$1
CODE=$2
#Find c:/user/Desktop/project
SCRIPT_PATH="$(pwd)"
#create a directory inside output folder
mkdir "/OUTPUT/NEW"
#make a copy of setup.txt file with a name of name-code
/bin/cp -p "OUTPUT/setup.txt" "OUTPUT/NEW/$NAME-$CODE.txt"
```

But this is not working .Is it correct code ? how can I make a folder and copy a file to that folder inside bash script ? How to correct this code ?

Comment: `mkdir OUTPUT/NEW`, not `mkdir /OUTPUT/NEW`. If it starts with a slash, it's an absolute path.

Comment: a back dot is appended with NEW folder when using mkdir .

Comment: What do you mean by "back dot"?

Comment: black dot is appended NEW .  instead of NEW folder

Answer (score 1):

1. `"$(pwd)"` gives a **working** folder, so if you call you script from `c:/user/Desktop/project/SCRIPT` it will be `c:/user/Desktop/project/SCRIPT`, but if you call it from `c:/` it will be `c:/`. It doesn't give your script location.
2. Creating a `"/OUTPUT/NEW"` folder will create a folder in the "root" directory. Strip leading slash if you want to use current directory or put a dot in front of it.

Comment: But it created a NEW . instead of NEW . A black dot is append with the folder . Why ?

Comment: What do you mean by "NEW . instead of NEW ."? And what do you mean by "black dot is append"?